# Display dynamic data as it loads instead of waiting for the backend script to finish

Tags: apache, ubuntu, centos, apache2, migrate

OK, I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here.. I'm migrating one of my servers from CentOS to Ubuntu LTS (this is not an enterprise install, so no "Ubuntu isn't an enterprise distro..." comments, please...) , and one if the quirks I've come across is in one of the scripts that gets run when clicking a button on a web page (fan relay control) takes several seconds to finish its' job...

On the CentOS install, the page loads the headers, etc., then prints each "SUCCESS" as the fan controller reports each fan command succeeded., then displays the rest of the page.

On the Ubuntu box, if you click on one of the fan command buttons, it runs the script, but appears to hang until the script is finished, then the page which ran the script (shtml) displays...

Is there a setting I'm missing in Apache2 that I'm missing to fix this, or is it something we'll have to live with...?

The apache install on the CentOS machine is different than the Ubuntu one, so I can't just copy config files over...

Comment: This is usually controlled by the scripting language, not Apache itself. If you're using something like PHP, you'll want to confirm what its flush settings are.

Comment: This is an SSI-initiated script, so it's something with mod_includes, methinks... (I just can't figure it out).  The PHP side of things works fine.

Comment: Well, crap.  After having to turn on the fans controlled by this machine on a machine other than my own (and using Chrome to do it instead of Firefox), I've come to the conclusion that the issue is with firefox and not apache or any of my code... Now to figure out why firefox is behaving this way...

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with Firefox, not apache.  I'll deal with why firefox is being stupid later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).